# How to show a window on top of all windows of the same application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a SplashScreen that should be shown in front of all other windows in the application.

Since it is a `SplashScreen`, this cannot be modal dialog. Instead, this should be shown by mean of other thread.

I create the splash screen this way:

```
            SplashScreenForm = new SplashScreen(mainForm);
            // SplashScreenForm.TopMost = true;
```

And to show it, I am using this call, called from a different thread:

```
Application.Run(SplashScreenForm);
```

If I uncomment `SplashScreenForm.TopMost = true`, the splash is shown on top of other windows, even on top of windows belonging to different applications.

If you want to know how the thread is created:

```
    public void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        SplashScreenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowForm));
        SplashScreenThread.IsBackground = true;
        SplashScreenThread.Name = "SplashScreenThread";
        SplashScreenThread.Start();
    }

    private static void ShowForm()
    {
        Application.Run(SplashScreenForm);
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why is there a need to show this dialog from another thread?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé because it should be shown while the main thread is loading the application (loading device drivers, some lists from database, and so on). While application is loaded, splash screen should show loading status.

Comment: Sounds a little odd to me to do heavy work in the gui thread and put actual gui elements into another thread. Why don't you shift the loading of your ressources (and whatever you need to do) to a worker thread and show your splashscreen from main thread?

Comment: That way is not feasible. First, startup operations cannot be made from other thread. Some of them, to make them thread safe, I need to implement some synchronization mechanism. It is more complicated. Second, please see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C. In introduction, it says which requirements a splash screen should meet. I did what that document says.

Comment: Isn't it common practice to close the splashscreen when your application has finished loading and thus is ready to display the main window? I'm not sure why you are focusing on this issue - to me, you either have the splashscreen open, or the application - not both at the same time.

Comment: most main interface loading occurs in Load event, so I don't know how to do it if I run the application first with Splash screen and when finish loading, show the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        delegate
        {
            splashForm = new SplashForm();
            Application.Run(splashForm);
        }
        ));

    splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    splashThread.Start();

    // Load main form and do lengthy operations
    MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
    mainForm.Load += new EventHandler(mainForm_Load);
    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

Then later after time-consuming operations are ended:

```
static void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (splashForm == null)
        return;
    splashForm.Invoke(new Action(splashForm.Close));
    splashForm.Dispose();
    splashForm = null;
}
```

This will start your splash screen *before* your main form and only dismiss it when the lengthy operations are completed in `mainForm_Load`.

Comment: Wonderful solution. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @jstuardo Glad to be of help.  You might want to upvote the answer so others will find it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling function `SetForegroundWindow(HWND)` from `WinAPI` :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// somewhere in the code :
SetForegroundWindow(SplashScreenForm.Handle);
```

Comment: I have tried it, however, the splash screen is shown at first, but almost immediately is hidden. I think it is due because main thread is still active loading some things.